# Typeorm - Cannot update entity because entity id is not set in the entity

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to save (insert) a new record in my DB but all i get is the error: `Cannot update entity because entity id is not set in the entity.`

What I'm currently doing:

```js
return this.connection.transaction(entityManager => {
   return entityManager.save(MyEntity, {/* payload without id */});
});
```

This is the only place in my codebase where this issue happen (transaction or not)

Comment: Given the claim that "it resolved itself," this is not a very good question. https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7643

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue today.  The wording of the error isn't perfect, so it distracts from the actual problem.  The actual problem is that the primary key (or part of a compound primary key) isn't provided and has no default.

In my case, it was an entity with a compound primary key, and one of the properties didn't have a default. We use unix_timestamp integers for dates, and you can't use unix_timestamp() as a default, so it has to be done by the application code.

The solution is most likely that you need to use the `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn` decorator instead of `@PrimaryColumn` if you want to use an auto-increment ID.

Otherwise, you need to provide a default the database can fill in, or use a `@BeforeInsert` decorator to make sure the property always gets populated before saving.

Answer (score 0):

TypeORM tracks entities with meta-data and most likely the id is still in the meta-data or has gotten in the meta-data. To fix this pass it through the create function.

```
return this.connection.transaction(entityManager => {
   // make sue payload is at this point already without id field else your problem will remain
   const entity = entityManager.create(payload)
   return entityManager.save(MyEntity, entity);
});
```

Most likely you are using a fetched entity as template, deleted the id, plus maybe some other settings and tried saving again.

Even though this might not be the exact way you got this error. This I see most commonly happen when this error occurs.

Comment: I think you're right, my issue was too light on explanation. I did use the create method but couldn't make it work nonetheless. I'm using a payload coming from class-validator, i'm assuming those metadata must be interfering with the one from typeorm. To fix my issue i rebuilt my project (docker, dist, everything). Thanks for your explanation @Funonly